# Button Press in jetpack compose showing multiple recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition, layout-inspector

[image]Hello the code is very simple on pressing a button i am changing the mutableState value.But i found the on button press recomposition is happening multiple time.

So is this some bug or for button the property is a bit different

Comment: Your button is animating. Recomposing in this scenario is no different than a View's onDraw method being called due to invalidation during an animation.

Comment: o I see, it makes sense now thanks. I didn't consider the animation. 

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the ripple effect that the button makes, you can do the following to stop this from happening:

```
class NoRippleInteractionSource() :  MutableInteractionSource {
override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()
override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}
override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true
}
```

And in your Button add this:

```
Button(
interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource(),
onClick = {  }) {
    Text("PressMe")
}
```